# if object exists in custom tag Django

Tags: django

This is my custom tag to show facebook link

```
@register.simple_tag
def facebook_link():
    if Facebook.objects.first():
        return str(Facebook.objects.first().link)
    else:
        return ''
```

I want to show a block of html if object exists, tried to do as follows but it still displays the block, when there is no object

```
{% if facebook_link %}
html goes here
{% endif %}
```

any idea how to do it

Comment: This means the object exists?

Comment: yes, this means the object exists, but if object is not there also it displays the html part

Comment: Return None instead of empty string?

Comment: You're using `facebook_link` as a variable, not as a tag.  `{% facebook_link %}` is a tag.

Comment: How can I check if object exists in that tag? Tried return None also, but the result is same

Comment: As @JohnGordon has suggested, try this: `{% facebook_link as my_link %}{% if my_link %}`

Comment: this throws the error TemplateSyntaxError, tried with endif also